# Please reopen "PHP: Object for HTML hyperlink"

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

The question [PHP: Object for HTML hyperlink](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201432/php-object-for-html-hyperlink) was closed as off-topic with the reason, "Lacks concrete context: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used."

When the question was first posted, a portion of the code was excluded and replaced with "..." because I thought it wasn't relevant to the question. I fixed this by inserting the missing portion of code. When I did that, I also added a second version of the code. After that, one of the people who voted to close the question said I should remove redundant code. So I removed the first version, while still leaving some information about that version, but only one version of the code now remains in the question.

I also tested the code myself and it works, and the question includes the output generated by the code. How much more concrete can it get? The purpose of the code is stated explicitly, "to generate HTML for hyperlinks embedded in text in PHP".

So how does this lack context? Or is there something else wrong with the question?

- Close review: [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/close/101949)
- Reopen review queue: [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/102001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it now has (more than) enough context, and that close reason is no longer valid. When it was closed, the question was confusing, and had other context problems.

Now that the question is cleared up, I can't see a reason to leave it closed. Note that it went through (and was kept closed) a reopen review queue before the bulk of the clean-up was done.

I'll reopen it to give it a fresh start....

Comment: As one of the close voters, I agree.